# Angular 10 $digest() iterations reached on random number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to generate random number for my images with lodash and every time i am clicking on image this should render again and i get the error:

**10 $digest() iterations reached.**

How can i do it?

```
  <footer ng-if="ArticleService.articles.length">
    <div ng-repeat="article in ArticleService.articles" ng-click="ArticleService.setArticle(article)">
     <img
      ng-src="{{article.image || 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/reskill_prod/static/images/a' + $index + '.jpg'}}">
      <img
      ng-src="{{'https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/static/images/a' + rand() + '.png'}}">
      <div class="info">
        <p>{{article.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

   $scope.rand = function() {
        return _.random(1, 12);
   }
```

Comment: Angular call digest loop, while scope changes. You should not call rand in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the random number on article and bind to that. Angular is going to keep digesting since the return value of `rand` keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

You should to stabilize your template.
Something like this:

```
  <footer ng-if="ArticleService.articles.length">
    <div ng-repeat="article in ArticleService.articles" ng-click="ArticleService.setArticle(article)">
     <img
      ng-src="{{article.image || 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/reskill_prod/static/images/a' + $index + '.jpg'}}">
      <img
      ng-src="{{'https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/static/images/a' + rand($index) + '.png'}}">
      <div class="info">
        <p>{{article.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>  


   var imgIndexes = {};
   $scope.rand = function(index) {
        return imgIndexes[index] || imgIndexes[index] = _.random(1, 12);
   }
```